# Joining unrelated Entities using JPQL not working in spring data with hibernate 5.3.2

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

I am not able to figure out what's wrong in following jpql query, which I am using in spring boot project with spring data and hibernate 5.3.2.

```
select t from MdmVehicle t join MdmVehicleGateInOut g with g.vehicleNumber = t.number
```

Below is the exception I am getting:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: in near line 1, column 68 [select t.number from in.ecomexpress.mdm.entities.MdmVehicle t join in.ecomexpress.mdm.entities.MdmVehicleGateInOut g with g.vehicleNumber = t.number]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:706)
    ... 172 more
```

Comment: I think the `in` in your package `in.ecomexpress.mdm.entities` causes this error. Could you try changing your packages not to have "in" ?

Comment: I don't think it's the problem. Reason: other joins are working fine where I have proper relationships between tables using foreign keys.

Comment: Moreover in your join criteria you use `with` ? is this valid? Shouldn't be `on` ?

Comment: I tried with ```on``` as well, same problem persists.

Comment: Moreover, if I remove join it works

Comment: Somewhere I have read that this is a feature of hibernate version 5, that means hql, and hql is superset of jpql. Is there any config to unlock this feature of hql? and Is it part of jpql spec?.

Comment: Tried in a demo on my own with package `in.example` and I get the same error. Changing it to `com.example` makes the error disappear. Its how hibernate validates/creates the query, it appends the fully qualified class name (including the packages) and after the "JOIN" keyword follows the "in" which is a reserved text and it breaks the query. Its all in the stacktrace you posted: `unexpected token: in near line 1, column 68 [select t.number from in.ecomexpress.mdm.entities.MdmVehicle t join in.ecomexpress.mdm.entities.MdmVehicleGateInOut g with g.vehicleNumber = t.number]`

Comment: I dont know how to override this, unless renaming "in" to something else. If you wonder how your other join queries work put your logger `logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG` in `application.properties` and examine lines containing `QueryTranslatorImpl` and `HqlParser`, e.g. in my logs: `o.h.h.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl   : parse() - HQL: SELECT s FROM in.example.demo.Student s JOIN in.example.demo.Course c ON s.courseKey=c.id`

Comment: Thanks to all of you! Yes, renaming the package name made the query work. This was "in" in the package name which was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed as part of https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10953 already and there are tests for this, so I have to assume you are using an older Hibernate version (i.e. not the one you think you are using).